# Non periodic sequence with $a_n=a_{n+k}=\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ which is non-periodic but for any $n\in\mathbb Z_+$, there exists $k\ge1$ so that $a_n=a_{n+k}=a_{n+2k}=\cdots$?

Here $(a_n)$ is non-periodic that is: for any $T\in\mathbb Z_+$ we could find $n\in\mathbb Z_+$ for which $a_n\neq a_{n+T}$.

It seems such sequence exist, but I have no idea to construct it.

Answer (score 2):

Start with $a_n=0$ if $n\equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

Now we only have odd indices to consider, thus $n\equiv 1,3 \pmod 4$.

Now say $a_n=1$ if $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  Now we only have $n\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ to consider, hence $n\equiv 3,7\pmod 8$.

So say $a_n=2$ if $n\equiv 3 \pmod 8$, leaving us with $n\equiv 7 \pmod 8$ so $n\equiv 7,15 \pmod {16}$.

And so on.

In general, we have $a_n=v_2(n+1)$, the order of divisibility of $n+1$ by $2$.

Comment: You mean odd indices, in your second line.

Comment: @junkquill  Thanks!  corrected.

Comment: Really good answer!

Answer (score 1):

One such sequence is given as$$1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1\ldots$$defined, for instance, by $a_n$ being the number of times $2$ goes into $2n$ ([OEIS reference](http://oeis.org/A001511))

It is never periodic, because $a_{2^n}$ is always larger than any earlier values, and specifically it's unequal to $a_{2^n-T}$ (as long as we pick $n$ large enough that it makes sense). But it has your property, since for each $n$ letting $k=2^{a_n}$ works.